# Discrete Math, Negation and Proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I hope we are all well.

I'm having a little hard time understand what negation means in Discrete maths.

Say I have "$2+5=19$" this would be a "Proposition" as its false. So how would I write the "negation". Would I say something like "$2$ plus $5$ does not equal $19$"?

The dictonary definition is: the absence or opposite of something actual or positive.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: The negation of a proposition is the assertion that the proposition is false.  So to do it very formally, the negation of $(2+5=19)$ is $\neg(2+5=19)$, which in more usual language is $(2+5\ne19)$.

Comment: BTW, sounds as if that "dictionary definition" came from an ordinary English dictionary... not really a good idea when looking up mathematical terms.  Mathematical terms are frequently *inspired* by ordinary English words, but they never mean exactly the same as ordinary English.

Comment: Thanks for that David. Your definiton of negation is better then the one in my text book :).

Comment: Yes indeed, I was reading about negation in the text book but I pulled the definition of google as I felt I was faster my bad..

Comment: Google should be OK as long as you make it clear you are looking for *mathematical* terminology.  Though maybe it would be simpler just to start with [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/) or something like that.

Comment: Yer Mathworld looks like the best bet..